# Getting unexpected Token error in sql query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: TOP near line 1, column 8 [SELECT TOP 10 IServe.ID FROM TopUp.dbo.IServe WHERE ExpireDate >= '2019-10-03'  AND TelcoID = '2' AND ProductID = '2' AND RechargeAmt = '100.0' AND Available = 1 ORDER BY ExpireDate, SN]

```
String query3 = "SELECT TOP " + importStockList.getOrderQuantity() +" IServe.ID FROM IServe WHERE "
            + " ExpireDate >= '" + sqlDate + "' " + " AND TelcoID = '" + importStockList.getTelcoId()
            + "' AND ProductID = '" + importStockList.getProductId() + "' AND " + "RechargeAmt = '"
            + importStockList.getRechargeAmt() + "' AND Available = 1 ORDER BY ExpireDate, SN" ;

    Session hbsessionSQL = HibernateUtilSQL.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Iserve> iserve = hbsessionSQL.createQuery(query3).list();
```

Can you please help me this error. I am stuck here

Comment: [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html) doesn't support "TOP" (or general SQL syntax - that's why it's called HQL and not SQL).

Comment: Should this not be `select .... LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: Have you looked into using `LIMIT 10` at the end of the statement rather than `TOP 10` at the start?

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after using LIMIT. FYI, I am using SQL database

Answer (score 1):

While your query is hard to read, and you should be using a prepared statement, I don't see anything wrong per se about the syntax.  So the error is probably happening because `TOP` is not valid HQL syntax.  `TOP` is really only supported on Microsoft databases, such as SQL Server or Access.  Try using `LIMIT` instead:

```
try {
    Session session = HibernateUtilSQL.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Connection conn = session.connection();
    String sql = "SELECT ID FROM IServe WHERE ExpireDate >= ? AND TelcoID = ? AND ProductID = ? AND RechargeAmt = ? AND Available = 1 ORDER BY ExpireDate, SN LIMIT ?";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setDate(1, sqlDate);
    ps.setInt(2, importStockList.getTelcoId());
    ps.setInt(3, importStockList.getProductId());
    ps.setInt(4, importStockList.getRechargeAmt());
    ps.setInt(5, importStockList.getOrderQuantity());
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {
        // process result set here
    }
}
catch(HibernateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its not understood what type your variables are, try to see the data by yourself. If there is an option string values contain special characters, remove them first.